# I want help in formulating a mixed integer linear problem formulation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-optimization, integer-programming

I want the following help in linear fashion:

- I have a vector: $P(n) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...,n]$
- I have binary variables with length of $P:y(1),y(2).....y(n)$. These variables, y(i) can only take $0$ or $1$.

A new vector $Q(n)$ is needed, such that, if $y(i)$ is $1$, then the $i^{th}$ element in $Q(n)$ should be $0$. And in rest of the places, the $P(n)$ should get repeated.

- Example : if $n = 6 $ , and $y(1)$ and $y(4)$ are $1$ ,then $Q(1)$ and $Q(4)$, should be $0$. The vector, $Q$ will be as follows :

$Q =$[**0** 1 2 **0** 1 2].

- Another example : if $y(3)$ is $1$, then $Q$ should be as follows:

$Q =$[1 2 **0** 1 2 3].

Basically, beside the zeros on $i^{th}$ position, the vector $P$ should repeat itself in non-zero positions of $Q$

Can you please help me formulating this problem?

Comment: You've already formulated the problem. What you need is a programmatic version of the variables and vectors, which is a question of computing, not mathematics.

Comment: Nope. I do not want it to be with if-else statements. I want this to be general, so that if any y(i) are ones / zeros, I should be able to WRITE LINEAR EQUATIONS to get Q ( given P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want to enforce:
$$Q_i = \begin{cases} 
0 &\text{if $y_i=1$} \\
1 &\text{if $y_i=0$ and $i=1$} \\
Q_{i-1} + 1 &\text{if $y_i=0$ and $i>1$} \\
\end{cases}$$
You can do this via linear constraints:
\begin{align}
1-y_i \le Q_i &\le i (1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag1\\
-iy_i \le Q_i - Q_{i-1} - 1 &\le -y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{2,\dots,n\}$} \tag2\\
\end{align}

- If $y_i=1$ then constraint $(1)$ enforces $Q_i=0$ and constraint $(2)$ enforces $-i \le 0-Q_{i-1}-1 \le -1$, which is redundant because $0 \le Q_j \le j$ for all $j$.
- If $y_i=0$ and $i=1$ then constraint $(1)$ enforces $Q_1=1$.
- If $y_i=0$ and $i>1$ then constraint $(2)$ enforces $Q_i=Q_{i-1}+1$ and constraint $(1)$ enforces $1 \le Q_i \le i$, which is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a doubt : multiplying indices (i) will not make it non-linear?

Comment: Each index $i$ is a constant, so everything is linear here.

Comment: The solution works extremely fine here. Only , it gives me error of : integer infeasibility if y('1')=1. Except that it works for all combinations of y(i). Also, I have a doubt: what if instead of [1,2,3,....n], we will have a known linear or other functional series (such as exponential etc.) with us? How do we implement it ? Just explain me, I will do it on my own. And thanks alot for your answer. I was trying it for 2 weeks. Also, can you suggest me, what to read to do practice of such problems? Thanks

Comment: I think you must have coded something wrong.  The trivial solution $y \equiv 1$ and $Q \equiv 0$ is feasible.

Comment: Yes sir. I'm sorry. It is indeed true ! Thanks

Comment: Also, can you suggest me a book, where I can solve such problems (converting such inequalities in linear equations).

Comment: The formulation here depends pretty strongly on $P$ having constant differences (arithmetic progression).  For an arbitrary $P$, I would probably instead use a network formulation.  Please post a separate question for that.  A good reference is Model Building in Mathematical Programming, and you might also check the modeling and linearization tags in https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. And I appreciate your help.

Comment: @RobPatt , Please see this new question with updated formulation. Basically, I should have made $P(n)$ arbitrary . In this question, it gives wrong impression of $P(n)$   
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230551/i-want-help-in-formulating-a-mixed-integer-linear-problem-formulation