# I want help in formulating a mixed integer linear problem formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want the following help in linear fashion (In my previous question, I asked the same but the solution was not generic. Please check it : [Prev.Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229627/i-want-help-in-formulating-a-mixed-integer-linear-problem-formulation)).

- I have an **arbitrary** vector: $P(n) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...,n]$. It can be $[10, 9, 5, 5,4, 3]$ , **basically any arbitrary vector , which will be defined beforehand**.
- I have binary variables with length of $P:y(1),y(2).....y(n)$. These variables, y(i) can only take $0$ or $1$.

A new vector $Q(n)$ is needed, such that, if $y(i)$ is $1$, then the $i^{th}$ element in $Q(n)$ should be $0$. And in rest of the places, the $P(n)$ should get repeated.

- Example : if $P = [8,5,6,1,2,3]$ and $y(1)$ and $y(4)$ are $1$ ,then $Q(1)$ and $Q(4)$, should be $0$. The vector, $Q$ will be as follows :

$Q =$[**0** 8 5 **0** 8 5].

- Another example : if $y(3)$ is $1$, then $Q$ should be:

$Q =$[8 5 **0** 8 5 6 1].

Basically, beside the zeros on $i^{th}$ position, the vector $P$ should repeat itself starting from $P(1)$ in non-zero positions of $Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a directed acyclic graph with nodes $N=\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}$ and arcs $(i,j)$ for $0 \le i < j \le n+1$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether $y_i=y_j=1$ and $y_{i+1}=\dots=y_{j-1}=0$.  Let $L_i$ and $U_i$ be constant lower and upper bounds on $Q_i$.  (In the linked question, $L_i=0$ and $U_i=i$.)  Impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_i &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,n+1\}$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} x_{i,j} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} x_{j,i} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$} \tag3 \\
L_i(1-y_i) \le Q_i &\le U_i(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag4 \\
Q_k &= \sum_{(i,j): i < k < j} P_{k-i} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag5
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ through $(3)$ yield a directed path from node $0$ to node $n+1$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $y_i=1 \implies Q_i=0$.
Constraint $(5)$ enforces $x_{i,j}=1 \implies Q_k = P_{k-i}$.

---

For your sample data, take $L_i=0$ and $U_i=\max_j P_j = 8$.  The constraints look like this:
\begin{equation}
y_{0} = 1 \\
y_{7} = 1 \\
x_{0,1} + x_{0,2} + x_{0,3} + x_{0,4} + x_{0,5} + x_{0,6} + x_{0,7} = y_{0} \\
x_{1,2} + x_{1,3} + x_{1,4} + x_{1,5} + x_{1,6} + x_{1,7} = y_{1} \\
x_{2,3} + x_{2,4} + x_{2,5} + x_{2,6} + x_{2,7} = y_{2} \\
x_{3,4} + x_{3,5} + x_{3,6} + x_{3,7} = y_{3} \\
x_{4,5} + x_{4,6} + x_{4,7} = y_{4} \\ 
x_{5,6} + x_{5,7} = y_{5} \\
x_{6,7} = y_{6} \\
x_{0,1} = y_{1} \\
x_{0,2} + x_{1,2} = y_{2} \\
x_{0,3} + x_{1,3} + x_{2,3} = y_{3} \\
x_{0,4} + x_{1,4} + x_{2,4} + x_{3,4} = y_{4} \\
x_{0,5} + x_{1,5} + x_{2,5} + x_{3,5} + x_{4,5} = y_{5} \\
x_{0,6} + x_{1,6} + x_{2,6} + x_{3,6} + x_{4,6} + x_{5,6} = y_{6} \\
x_{0,7} + x_{1,7} + x_{2,7} + x_{3,7} + x_{4,7} + x_{5,7} + x_{6,7} = y_{7} \\
0 \le Q_{1} \le 8(1-y_{1}) \\
0 \le Q_{2} \le 8(1-y_{2}) \\
0 \le Q_{3} \le 8(1-y_{3}) \\
0 \le Q_{4} \le 8(1-y_{4}) \\
0 \le Q_{5} \le 8(1-y_{5}) \\
0 \le Q_{6} \le 8(1-y_{6}) \\
Q_{1} = 8x_{0,2} + 8x_{0,3} + 8x_{0,4} + 8x_{0,5} + 8x_{0,6} + 8x_{0,7} \\
Q_{2} = 5x_{0,3} + 5x_{0,4} + 5x_{0,5} + 5x_{0,6} + 5x_{0,7} + 8x_{1,3} + 8x_{1,4} + 8x_{1,5} + 8x_{1,6} + 8x_{1,7} \\
Q_{3} = 6x_{0,4} + 6x_{0,5} + 6x_{0,6} + 6x_{0,7} + 5x_{1,4} + 5x_{1,5} + 5x_{1,6} + 5x_{1,7} + 8x_{2,4} + 8x_{2,5} + 8x_{2,6} + 8x_{2,7} \\
Q_{4} = x_{0,5} + x_{0,6} + x_{0,7} + 6x_{1,5} + 6x_{1,6} + 6x_{1,7} + 5x_{2,5} + 5x_{2,6} + 5x_{2,7} + 8x_{3,5} + 8x_{3,6} + 8x_{3,7} \\
Q_{5} = 2x_{0,6} + 2x_{0,7} + x_{1,6} + x_{1,7} + 6x_{2,6} + 6x_{2,7} + 5x_{3,6} + 5x_{3,7} + 8x_{4,6} + 8x_{4,7} \\
Q_{6} = 3x_{0,7} + 2x_{1,7} + x_{2,7} + 6x_{3,7} + 5x_{4,7} + 8x_{5,7}  
\end{equation}

For your sample solution with $y_0=y_1=y_4=y_7=1$ and all other $y_i=0$, the constraints imply that $x_{0,1}=x_{1,4}=x_{4,7}=1$ and all other $x_{i,j}=0$.  Now compute $Q$ based on these values of $x$ and $y$ to help understand how the formulation works.

---

Edit: You can omit $(4)$, which is already implied by $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(5)$.

Comment: I did not understand about : $y$ here. In this case, our decision variable is $x(i,j)$. What are $y(i)$ and $y(j)$ here? Are these also binary variables? And are we defining additional variable $x(i,j)$ for our convenience? Also, I cannot understand, using $arc(i,j)$. Where are we using the directed acyclic graph in equations?

Comment: The $y_i$ is your original binary decision variable.  I updated the summation indices in $(2)$ and $(3)$ to make the arcs explicit.

Comment: If $y(i)$ is my binary decision variable, why condition # $(1)$ says $y(i)=1$. I may also have $y(i)=0$

Comment: Constraint $(1)$ forces $y_i=1$ only for the two artificial nodes $0$ and $n+1$, which are the endpoints of the directed path.

Comment: In second line of solution , it is written as $0 \le i < j \le n+1$. It mean maximum of $i$ is $n$. Then should the first constraint be changed as : $y(0)=1$.

Comment: The arcs $(i,j)$ satisfy $i\le n$, but the nodes $i$ and $j$ are in $\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}$.  Constraint $(1)$ is correct as written.  You want both $y_0=1$ and $y_{n+1}=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Now I understood almost all things. I have partially implemented it. I will reply here with my results. Thank you very much for your valuable help !

Comment: Dear Dr. RobPratt , I m trying to understand and implement the above solution. however I think, it is beyond the scope of my understanding. Can you please tell me , what should i specifically read to understand above ?

Comment: I just added to my answer the explicit constraints for your example.  I recommend substituting the fixed values of $y$ and $x$ and using the constraints to deduce the values of $Q$ as a helpful learning exercise.  It is also useful to deduce $x$ from the fixed values for $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I could successfully formulate it. However, I am solving an MILP (mixed integer linear programming). I wanted to use the $Q$ generated above. However, now a different problem is raised. $Q$ is multiplied by another variable. Thus the problem has become nonlinear again. I used to thought, we have made up the $Q$ using a known vector, $P$ and only binary variable $y$. Unfortunately, I cannot linearize my system.  Therefore, I was about to use McCormick method to get done. Can you please shade some light on it ? Or the system, thus, is inherently nonlinear ?

Comment: Please post a new question for your new problem.

Comment: I think there is a correction in the formulae mentioned : $x_{0,1} + x_{0,2} + x_{0,3} + x_{0,4} + x_{0,5} + x_{0,6} + x_{0,7} = y_{0}  $ and $x_{0,7} + x_{1,7} + x_{2,7} + x_{3,7} + x_{4,7} + x_{5,7} + x_{6,7} = y_{7} $ should be avoided. I removed these and then I am getting correct answers.. Otherwise some $y(i)$ are forced to be 1.

Comment: No, those two constraints are correct.  And we do want $y_0=y_7=1$, but no other $y_i$ are forced.  Note that the two constraints you mentioned can both be satisfied by taking $x_{0,7}=1$ and all other $x_{i,j}=0$.

Comment: Dear Dr. Rob . Please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236859/linearization-of-product-of-a-continuous-and-a-discrete-variable

Comment: Can there be any generalized way to make one zero , two zeros.... in this formulation (e.g. $[8,5,0,8,5,6,1],[8,5,0,0,8,5,6], [8,5,0,0,0,8,6,1]$)

Comment: The arc definitions control how many consecutive zeros are allowed.  To disallow a certain number, omit the corresponding arcs from the problem, thereby reducing the number of $x_{i,j}$ variables.

Comment: The solution approach is extremely well. However, if taken in a larger sense, the number of binary variables are very large. It takes enormous time to solve the model.

Comment: What is your objective? Also, if you have bounds on the length of the gap between values of $1$ for $y$, you can omit some of the arcs and thereby reduce the number of $x$ variables.

Comment: The objective is to find optimum $y_i$, which will reduce a cost function, which has $y_i$s in it ( linear). I omitted many arcs, as per one of your suggestions. In actuality, $y_i$ denotes a schedule of on and off of a machine. I have several such machines. Here, $i$ denotes time. I have $y(Machine,time)$. The model , since consists a lot of such machines for large duration, the number of binary variables exploding.  The objective is to minimize the addition of operating costs of all machines and profit. The profit requires all machines to run whereas the op.cost requires machines to be off

Comment: In addition to above, the states of machine changes with time ( as shown by vector $P$ in our problem).

Comment: I have, to be very frank, have understood the logic behind the formulation, I have modified the formulation ( reducing arcs, reducing the linear inequality equations to the minimum level). I assume that there is no scope to reduce the problem further. Somewhere, in the literature I have read that MILP always have to face this issue of large computational durations. I'm using CPLEX. I tried several options. When the nos of machines is small, problem converges in minutes, however as I add more machines and time, it takes exponential time to converge.