# Want to form the linear equations for conditions given below:

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to formulate the **set of linear equations** for the following conditions:

- $Q(i) = 0$ if $y(i)=1$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$
- $Q(i) = P(i)$, if $\sum_{j=1}^{n}{y(j)}=0$ for $j \le i$.
- $Q(i) = P(i-r)$, if $\sum_{j=1}^{r}{y(j)}\le r$ , and $y(r)=1$ and $y(i)=0$, where $ 0<r<i $

$y(i)$ is binary term $[0,1]$.

**Example:**

- **Given**

Let $P = [ 1,4,6,7,8,1,90]$

Here, the length of $P$ is $7$, i.e. $(n =7)$

Let $y = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0]$. Note that length of $y$ and $P$ are equal.

So the indices : $i = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and $r = 1,2,3,4,5,6$.

- **Calculation of $Q(i)$, which also has length $n$ are provided on the attached image [image: This image shows the example]file**

Comment: In the second and third bullets, the indexing doesn't make sense.

Comment: In second  , if summation of all $y(i)$ is zero , Or each $y(i)$ is zero , $Q(i)$ should be equal to $P(i)$

Comment: HI, can you please let me know, what part is not clear? Because, as I see them ( which may be wrong due to my not so good understanding), the conditions are correct.

Comment: You have used $i$ in three different ways in the second bullet.

Comment: I think, now it is formulated correctly.

Comment: No, you are back where you started,

Comment: I want to write the equations in words: For a given $i$,
A. $Q(i)$ is 0, if $y(i)$ is one.

B. if all $y(i)$s are zero, then $Q(i)=P(i)$.

C. If $y(i)$ is zero and $y(r)$ is one {where, $r$ is less than $i$} , then $Q(i)$ will be $P(i-r)$.

$r$ is a positive number less than $i$

Comment: Is it clear now? If no, I request you to please tell me , what is not clear. I am not understanding it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, B and C still are not clear. Please provide examples like you did for your other two related questions.

Comment: I have added an example to explain my conditions, also , initially I wrote $ 0 \le r \le i $, which is wrong. It should be $ 0 < r < i $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128851/discussion-between-parag-and-robpratt).

Comment: You still have some indexing issues, but your example looks like you are asking the same thing as [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230551/i-want-help-in-formulating-a-mixed-integer-linear-problem-formulation) that I answered yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But looking at the examples, can you tell me where am I making mistake in indices?

Comment: Yes. The problem is similar. But I thought, if I get this corrected, it can also be a way to solve that problem.

Comment: I don't see any difference at all.  Your desired $Q$ is exactly the same in both problems.  Your $\sum_1^i y_i$ doesn't make sense.  I think you meant instead if $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = 0$, then $Q_i = P_i$ for all $i$.  In many places, you are simultaneously fixing $i$ and using it as a summation index.

Comment: I think, now the edit is correct. I desired $Q$ same in both the problems. However, I am trying here to make the Linear Equations , which can take any $P$. I appreciate your acyclic diagraph method. However, I think if my formulation here is correct, it will be easy to follow (I may be wrong but then, please correct me, If I am wrong). I appreciate your help.