# Linearization of product of a continuous and a discrete variable

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

From my [previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230551/957295), I have a variable : $Q$, which is function of a **discrete known vector, $P$** and a binary variable **$x$** : $Q=f(P,x)$.

- I know, we can linearize the products of (a) two / multiple binary variables (b) binary and a continuous variable as described in this [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables#:%7E:text=The%20general%20case%20with%20n%20binary%20variables&text=Suppose%20we%20have%20n%20binary,%E2%88%92(n%E2%88%921).)
- I'm also aware that its difficult to formulate a linear way of separating 2 continuous variables as described in [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-continuous-variables)

But in my case, **the variable $Q$ is made up of a known parameter and a discrete variable**. Thus, how to linearize the system?

From the [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230626/957295): For a directed acyclic graph with nodes $N=\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}$ and arcs $(i,j)$ for $0 \le i < j \le n+1$.  A binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ is declared, which shows whether $y_i=y_j=1$ and $y_{i+1}=\dots=y_{j-1}=0$.  It uses the upper and lower limits : $L_i$ and $U_i$ on $Q_i$. Following linear equations were to be imposed:
\begin{align}
y_i &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,n+1\}$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} x_{i,j} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} x_{j,i} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$} \tag3 \\
L_i(1-y_i) \le Q_i &\le U_i(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag4 \\
Q_k &= \sum_{(i,j): i < k < j} P_{k-i} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag5
\end{align}

Now, let us have a continuous variable $T_k$ for $k \in \ {1,\dots, n } $. This variable is multiplied to the variable used previously as : $Q_k.T_k$.

I tried linearizing this with the following approach. However, my problem is integer infeasible.

First, let me put the full equations as per above mentioned equations $(1) to (5)$ from previous answer:

Based on this, following is the different set of equations (which are changed due to multiplied $T_k$ to $Q_k$):

\begin{equation}
0 \le Q_{1}.T_{1} \le 8.T_{1}.(1-y_{1}) \\
0 \le Q_{2}.T_{2} \le 8.T_{2}.(1-y_{2}) \\
0 \le Q_{3}.T_{3} \le 8.T_{3}.(1-y_{3}) \\
0 \le Q_{4}.T_{4} \le 8.T_{4}.(1-y_{4}) \\
0 \le Q_{5}.T_{5} \le 8.T_{5}.(1-y_{5}) \\
0 \le Q_{6}.T_{6} \le 8.T_{6}.(1-y_{6}) \\
Q_{1}.T_{1} = T_{1}.[8x_{0,2} + 8x_{0,3} + 8x_{0,4} + 8x_{0,5} + 8x_{0,6} + 8x_{0,7}] \\
Q_{2}.T_{2} = T_{2}[5x_{0,3} + 5x_{0,4} + 5x_{0,5} + 5x_{0,6} + 5x_{0,7} + 8x_{1,3} + 8x_{1,4} + 8x_{1,5} + 8x_{1,6} + 8x_{1,7}] \\
Q_{3}.T_{3} = T_{3}[6x_{0,4} + 6x_{0,5} + 6x_{0,6} + 6x_{0,7} + 5x_{1,4} + 5x_{1,5} + 5x_{1,6} + 5x_{1,7} + 8x_{2,4} + 8x_{2,5} + 8x_{2,6} + 8x_{2,7}] \\
Q_{4}.T_{4} = T_{4}[x_{0,5} + x_{0,6} + x_{0,7} + 6x_{1,5} + 6x_{1,6} + 6x_{1,7} + 5x_{2,5} + 5x_{2,6} + 5x_{2,7} + 8x_{3,5} + 8x_{3,6} + 8x_{3,7}] \\
Q_{5}.T_{5} = T_{5}[2x_{0,6} + 2x_{0,7} + x_{1,6} + x_{1,7} + 6x_{2,6} + 6x_{2,7} + 5x_{3,6} + 5x_{3,7} + 8x_{4,6} + 8x_{4,7}] \\
Q_{6}.T_{6} = T_{6}[3x_{0,7} + 2x_{1,7} + x_{2,7} + 6x_{3,7} + 5x_{4,7} + 8x_{5,7}]  
\end{equation}

In above equations, we can see that $T_k.y_k$ and $T_k.x_{i,j}$ are present. Since, these are pairs of continuous and binary variables, These are linearized as follows:

From $1^{st}$ to $6^{th}$ equations:

\begin{equation}
0 \le Q_{k}.T_{k} \le 8.T_{k}.(1-y_{k})
\end{equation}
Above is written as follows:

\begin{equation}
0 \le Z_{k} \le 8.T_{k} - 8TY_{k} \\
T_{k} - UL(T)(1-y_k) \le TY_{k} \le T_{k}-LL(T)(1-y_k) \\
LL(T)y_k \le UL(T)y_k\\
\end{equation}

where , $Z_{k} = T_{K}.Q_{K}$ , $TY_{k}$ is an assumed new variable for product of $T_{k}$ and $y_K$. $LL(T)$ and $UL(T)$ are lower and upper limits (which are known) on $T_k$.

Next, the remained equations ($7^{th}$ to $12^{th}$) are as  follows:

\begin{equation}
Z_{1} = T_{1}8\sum_{i=2}^{7}x_{0,i}\\
Z_{2} = T_{2} (5\sum_{i=3}^{7}x_{0,i} + 8\sum_{i=3}^{7}x_{1,i})\\
Z_{3} = T_{3}(6\sum_{i=4}^{7}x_{0,i} + 5\sum_{i=3}^{7}x_{1,i} + 8\sum_{i=3}^{7}x_{2,i})\\
Z_{4} = T_{4}(\sum_{i=5}^{7}x_{0,i} + 6\sum_{i=5}^{7}x_{1,i} + 5\sum_{i=5}^{7}x_{2,i} + 8\sum_{i=5}^{7}x_{3,i})\\
Z_{5} = T_{5}(2\sum_{i=6}^{7}x_{0,i} + 1\sum_{i=6}^{7}x_{1,i} + 6\sum_{i=6}^{7}x_{2,i} + 5\sum_{i=6}^{7}x_{3,i} + 8\sum_{i=6}^{7}x_{4,i})\\
Z_{6} = T_{6}(3\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{0,i} + 2\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{1,i} + 1\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{2,i} + 6\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{3,i} + 5\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{4,i}+ 8\sum_{i=7}^{7}x_{5,i})
\end{equation}

In each equation above, for every $Z_k$, the pairs of $T_k$ and corresponding $x_{i,j}$ is linearized by assuming them as another new variable as ZZ(k,i,j).

Despite the procedure followed above, I get an error of 'the equations are not feasible'.

Can you please let me know, where is the problem? I cannot find it.

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Comment: By $f$ I meant the set of equations which are written by you in previous problem. The way, $Q$ is calculated.

Comment: So, the point is : $Q(k)$ is calculated in previous question. But there is another continuous variable $T(k) $ , getting multiplied to $Q(k)$. How to linearize this case?

Comment: Please edit the question to show how $T(k)$ appears in the problem.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the product $Q_k T_k$ appear in your problem?  And does $T_k$ have bounds?

Comment: $Q_k.T_k$ comes in my objective function of optimization problem. And $T_k$ has bounds. $T_k \ge 0$ and $T_k \le TT_k $. I know all values of $TT_k$

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information, and please explicitly show the objective function.

Comment: Hi, Dr. Rob. I have solved this problem. But since I'm new on this portal. Can I answer my own question? Or should I delete this one? Can you please suggest me appropriate action?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Dear Dr. @RobPratt , Can you please help me in this? I tried to do the linearization with additional variable, but I do not understand, why I am failing. Is the edited set of equations based on your previous answer is correct? I have mentioned only those equations, which has additional variable multiplied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following strategy works fine :**

Define a directed acyclic graph with nodes $N=\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}$ and arcs $(i,j)$ for $0 \le i < j \le n+1$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether $y_i=y_j=1$ and $y_{i+1}=\dots=y_{j-1}=0$.  Let $L_i$ and $U_i$ be constant lower and upper bounds on $Q_i$.Impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_i &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,n+1\}$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} x_{i,j} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} x_{j,i} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$} \tag3 \\
\end{align}

Now , if $T_k$ comes into picture, add following :

\begin{align}
LL(T) x_{i,j} &\le z_{i,j,k} \le UL(T) x_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j$ and $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$} \tag4 \\
(0 - UL(T))(1 - x_{i,j}) &\le z_{i,j,k} - T_k \le (0 - LL(T))(1 - x_{i,j}) &&\text{for all $i,j$ and $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$} \tag5 \\
zz_{i,j,k}  &= \sum_{(i,j):i<k<j}P_{k-i}z_{i,j,k} \tag6
\end{align}

(The above answer is extension of solution provided by @RobPratt . The Link is : [Previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230626/957295))

Comment: Yes, you have accurately captured the model.  Impose constraints (1) through (7), and replace $Q_k T_k$ in the objective.

Comment: @RobPratt, equation 4 and 5 are becoming useless in this setting sir. If I will replace $Q_k.T_k$ by last one, where equation 4 and 5 will come into picture? They r going out. Please see, why even equation 4 and 5 are needed then?

Comment: Not sure why you think they are useless. They enforce the behavior you want. To convince yourself, try it both ways (with or without (4) and (5)) and compare the results.

Comment: Hi, @RobPratt, I have explained the reason, why I think that equations (4) and (5) are not making sense to me in above answer (requesting you to pl. see above answer, where I have added the reason). It might be totally wrong , but I am really confused there.

Comment: Without (4), nothing enforces $Q_i=0$ (hence $Q_iT_i=0$) when $y_i=1$.

Comment: Sir, but in our model, there is no $Q_i.T_i$. As it is replaced by new term.

Comment: Do you want $\sum P_{k-i} x_{i,j} T_k$ to be $0$ when $y_k=1$?  If you omit $(4)$ and $(5)$, nothing enforces that behavior.

Comment: Sir, I understand that. But since I replace the equation by another one, $Q_k$ is totally absent in my system. I cannot understand, why is it difficult to understand by all this thing. The $obj$ itself has no $Q_k$.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that $(4)$ is not needed here or in your previous question.  The implication $y_k  = 1 \implies Q_k = 0$ is already enforced by the flow balance constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$.  If $y_k = 1$ then $x_{i,j} = 0$ for all $(i,j)$ with $i<k<j$, which forces both $Q_k$ and $Q_k T_k =0$.  For the current question, you can omit $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Comment: I omitted it, but for all $i,j,k$ the problem is becoming infeasible. I'm really stuck and nervous here ! But anyways. thank you.

Comment: What are your values of LL and UL?

Comment: LL is zero in most cases ( it's temperature) . UL is a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

From (5), \begin{align*}
Q_{k}\cdot T_{k} & =\sum_{(i,j):i<k<j}P_{k-i}x_{i,j}T_{k}\\
 & =\sum_{(i,j):i<k<j}P_{k-i}z_{ijk}
\end{align*}where $z_{ijk}=x_{ij}T_k$. Now use the approach mentioned in your question to linearize the product $x_{ij}T_k$ (binary times continuous).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prepared the same. And was about to write the same. But this is exactly what I did. Directly multiplied the binary variable with continuous and then finally multiplied by constants.

Comment: Dear prubin, I tried your solution approach, but I'm not able to get the correct answer. I cannot understand why. Can you please see the edited question to identify where is actual mistake?

Comment: The edited question is a bit hard to read. To diagnose the problem, try the following. First, figure out by hand a feasible solution to the actual problem. Next, fix every variable at the value in that solution by setting lower bound = upper bound = value. Now run the model through your solver, which presumably will declare it infeasible. Once that happens, ask the solver for a minimal set of inconsistent constraints (also known as an irreducible infeasible subset or IIS). Most solvers can do this. Assuming your solution really should be feasible, at least one of those constraints is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Leave constraints $(1)$ through $(3)$ as they are.  You do not need variables to represent $T_k y_k$ or $Q_k T_k$.  Instead, as in @prubin's suggestion, introduce a new continuous variable $z_{i,j,k}$ to represent $x_{i,j} T_k$, together with linear constraints
\begin{align}
LL(T) x_{i,j} &\le z_{i,j,k} \le UL(T) x_{i,j} &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \tag6 \\
(0 - UL(T))(1 - x_{i,j}) &\le z_{i,j,k} - T_k \le (0 - LL(T))(1 - x_{i,j}) &&\text{for all $i,j,k$}\tag7 \\
\end{align}
Constraint $(6)$ enforces $x_{i,j} = 0 \implies z_{i,j,k} = 0$.
Constraint $(7)$ enforces $x_{i,j} = 1 \implies z_{i,j,k} = T_k$.
Together, these enforce $z_{i,j,k} = x_{i,j} T_k$.

Now replace $Q_k T_k$ in your objective with $$\sum_{(i,j):i<k<j}P_{k-i}z_{i,j,k}.$$

---

Edit: You can omit $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Comment: I understood the reply from you as well as @prubin. But I don't understand, why equation 1 through 6 here need not to change? Because, $Q_k$ and $T_k$ are when together, their upper limit (in equation 1 to 6) will also change right? For instance, if $y_k$ is 0, then upper limit for $Q_k$ in this case should not only be $P_k$ but $P_k.T_k$ . Am I missing something here?

Comment: So you are suggesting about equation 5, in your original answer to be modified. However, I'm worried about equation number 4. Will the limits not change in new case?

Comment: The relationships among $x$, $y$, $P$, and $Q$ are still the same, and the original constraints (1) through (5) enforce those.