# Alternate approach to formulate this MIP

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

This is in concern to reformulating a previously formulated set of linear equations in my previous question: [This is the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230551/i-want-help-in-formulating-a-mixed-integer-linear-problem-formulation/4230626#4230626)

\begin{align}
y_i &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{0,n+1\}$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{j=i+1}^{n+1} x_{i,j} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{0,\dots,n\}$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} x_{j,i} &= y_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$} \tag3 \\
L_i(1-y_i) \le Q_i &\le U_i(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag4 \\
Q_k &= \sum_{(i,j): i < k < j} P_{k-i} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag5
\end{align}

I formulated a MIP problem based on the above. Unfortunately, the set of the above equations becomes very large that the MIP takes enormous amount of time to solve. I'm using GAMS/GUROBI.

I wanted to pose this question here, I wanted to know if we can simplify above set of equations, so that it may help.

Comment: If $y_i=1$ for all $i$, as specified by (1), why is it included as a variable?

Comment: @prubin Not all $i$, just $i=0$ and $i=n+1$ (the two endpoints of the path).

Comment: @RobPratt Oops, missed the lack of ellipsis.

Comment: @prubin I have not added full prev. problem here. The nature of prev.the problem requires it like this.

Answer (score 0):

One simplification is to omit $(4)$, which was identified as redundant in the linked question.  It is possible that the presolver already eliminates these, but it is worth trying explicitly omitting them.

Comment: Hello Dr. RobPratt, I am writing paper based on the formulation in which you have helped me. Can you please tell me, how to acknowledge you? Can I write, that the discusson with you helped me in problem formulation in acknowledgment ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine with me.  There are some suggestions here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathematics-stack-exchange-in-my-thesis-paper  There is also a Cite button for each question or answer.

Comment: I think, I will acknowledge you and then in the link, I will cite the modified final answer based on which I made GAMS program. Thank you very much for your help.